# Setup Firebug to only be enabled for certain web sites

Tags: firebug

How can I setup Firebug to **always** be active when going to `http://localhost/...` and to **never** be active when browsing other sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered in the FAQ (shame on me for asking it here!):

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Enable_Firebug_1.4_and_1.5_for_specific_sites